# Socket IO ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on Digital Oceans App platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, digital-ocean

I am deploying my app on digital ocean's app platform. My frontend react app and backend express app are under the same "app" as different components.
I have having trouble connecting to my socket.io web socket server through my client. I am using my own domain, and I get this following error when connecting to my socket io server:
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:8080/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`
My socket io server listens on port 5000 and my react client is on port 8080, and I have a route to my service (where the socket io server lives) at /api. The socket io endpoint I am trying to connect to is "https://example.com/api".
On local development, I have a similar setup and this works. Locally, I listen to port 5000, and I use the endpoint I use is "http://127.0.0.1:5000". What can I do to connect to my socket io server from my client on the app platform? My https endpoints through https://example.com/api works, but I just can't connect to the socket io server.

backend service:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {  
  cors: {    
    origin: [CLIENT_URL],
    credentials: true  
  }
});

// Socket io middleware
const wrap = (middleware: any) => (socket: any, next: any) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
io.use(wrap(sessionMiddleware));
io.use(wrap(passport.initialize()));
io.use(wrap(passport.session()));
io.use(wrap(isLoggedIn));
fishingSocket(io, fishingController);
server.listen(POND_SERVICE_PORT, () => console.log('Server Running'));
```

react client:

```
const webSocket = io(`${process.env.SERVICE_ENDPOINT}`, {  withCredentials: true});
```

I have tried setting the socker io endpoint url to http, but that did not work either.